# C# Set of Objects Referenced by Class

Tags: c#, .net, collections, set

What I want is a unique collection, or set, of objects referenced by their class. This set can only contain one object of a given class. Here is an example of some possible functionality:

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();

UnknownCollection<object> objects;
objects.Add(A, a);    // Add(key, value)
objects.Add(B, b);
objects.Add(C, c);
var something = objects[A]; // return a reference to 'a' using class A as a key
```

If something along these lines doesn't already exist, might there be a way to create one with reasonable performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you really want a `Dictionary<Type, object>` which you populate with:

```
objects.Add(typeof(A), a);
objects.Add(typeof(B), a);
objects.Add(typeof(C), a);
...

A a = (A) objects[typeof(A)];
```

If the dictionary always maps a type to an instance of that type, you can encapsulate that so you can keep the API clean. You always know the cast will work, because the only code which can add to the dictionary ensures that the type is always correct.

EDIT: Aha - it turns out I [blogged about this back in 2008](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/mapping-from-a-type-to-an-instance-of-that-type.aspx).

Comment: And I'd suggest this extension method to make it easier to populate correctly: `public static void Add<TValue>(this IDictionary<Type, TValue> self, TValue value) { self.Add(value.GetType(), value); }`

Comment: @cdhowie: I would encapsulate it within a separate type, rather than letting just anything get at it.

Comment: Yes, that would be preferred.. but for a quick and dirty hack, an extension method is better than nothing.  :)

Comment: Excellent, I had a hunch that Dictionary would serve my purposes, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet In your blog post, you have `public void Add<T>(T value) { dictionary.Add(typeof(T), value); }`.  This makes it possible to do `dict.Add<Base>(someDerived)` -- was this intended?

Comment: @cdhowie If someone using your tool wants to shoot themselves in the foot, there's only so far you can go to stop them.  The class makes it easy to do the "proper" thing, and harder (but still possible) to abuse it and not use it as intended.

Comment: @Servy Well, it's not like `public void Add(object value) { dictionary.Add(value.GetType(), value); }` (plus a null test) is that much harder.  I'm just wondering if this was a design decision or an oversight.

Comment: @cdhowie: You can implement it as `public void Add<T>(T value) { dictionary.Add(value.GetType(), value); }` to use the actual type of the object, if that is preferred.

Comment: @Guffa You can, yes, but the use of generics doesn't really accomplish anything; if the object is a reference type then no boxing will be performed in either case, and if the object is a value type then it will be boxed anyway.  Generics add unnecessary complexity at runtime.

Comment: @cdhowie: Absolutely. It's safe to do, and I can't see why you'd want to prohibit it. If the method *weren't* generic, you'd have no way of adding a string as the value for type `Object`, despite the fact that it clearly *is* an object. This is particularly bad when you want to register values for interface types.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, so it's intended then.  Thanks, that's what I was wondering.  :)  The interface example makes sense.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, for the `Add` method it doesn't make much difference, but the `Get` method gets a lot more convenient.

Comment: @Guffa Yes indeed, generics make perfect sense for the Get method, since it allows the implementation to hide the cast.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, specifically with type as a key:

```
Dictionary<Type, object> map = new Dictionary<Type, object>()
{
    { typeof(A), a }
    { typeof(B), b }
};
```